# Emit socket event in applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io, applicationwillterminate

I am trying to emit a socket event in **applicationWillTerminate** in `AppDelegate`. I have used `socket.io`.

I believe I am able to successfully emit the event.
Following are the logs I get in the console :

> 2018-10-08 20:29:45.663856+0530 SOCKET_POC[4718:303986] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Emitting: 23["device-disconnect","{\"QrcodeID\":\"2a758b00-314f-d69d-a10b-24fca56693ed\",\"UniqueID\":\"E15C087D-626F-4F10-B0B3-7567DA76EF51\"}"], Ack: false
>   2018-10-08 20:29:49.561608+0530 SOCKET_POC[4718:304214] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws: 23["device-disconnect","{\"QrcodeID\":\"123\",\"UniqueID\":\"123\"}"] has data: false
>   2018-10-08 20:29:49.561675+0530 SOCKET_POC[4718:304214] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws: 23["device-disconnect","{\"QrcodeID\":\"123\",\"UniqueID\":\"123\"}"] as type: 4

Please find the code below :

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print(SocketHandler.instance?.socket.status)
    if let uniqueId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Constants.USER_DEFAULT_KEYS.UINQUE_ID) as? String {

        CommonFunctions().emitResultOnDeviceDisconnect(qrcode: "\(Variables.QRCodeID)", uniqueId: uniqueId)
        print(SocketHandler.sharedInstance().socket.status)
}
```

I have even printed the status of my socket which always prints connected.

But when I see the logs at the server(backend), they don't receive my emitted socket event at all.

Comment: I reckon you want to get a utility like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and make sure that your packets are actually leaving your device.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.Swift,
change your "applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)" to  Following code ==>

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0;
    bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName:"MyBackgroundTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        print("The task has started")
        application.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    })
}
```

And keep your logic of "applicationWillTerminate" as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire socket event as soon as you kill the application, you need to create a background task as from the apple's developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate).

```
optional func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
```

You should use this method to perform any final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources, saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this method has approximately **five seconds** to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

What you can do is create a background task to fire the socket event so that if we are supposed to receive a callback, we can get in time.

Please follow the following code to resolve the problem you are facing:

**Add this property in your Appdelegate**

```
var taskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

**Add the following methods**

```
func startBackgroundTask() {
  taskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
    })
    // Only to check if the task is in invalid state or not for debugging.
    assert(task != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskIdentifier)
    taskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let uniqueId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Constants.USER_DEFAULT_KEYS.UINQUE_ID) as? String {
       CommonFunctions().emitResultOnDeviceDisconnect(qrcode: "\(Variables.QRCodeID)", uniqueId: uniqueId)
    }
    self.startBackgroundTask()
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem. In case of any issues please feel free to as in loop.

Thanks.